# This is about jenkins environment dashboard plugin.

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using jenkins 1.532.  I have installed Jenkins environment dashboard plugin.  Created dashboard view, then I configured two of the deployment jobs to populate the dashboard with details.  However, the dashboard is not displaying the details of the second deployment job.  It always displays the details from first job.  Has anyone tried using jenkins environment dashboard plugin with various environments and products. 
I also tried to delete the dashboard view but Jenkins is not allowing the deletion also.
Can anyone help me as to why the dashboard is not picking details from second job and not allowing me to delete the dashboard view??

Comment: I honestly think it'll be easier for you to [open an issue](https://github.com/vipinsthename/environment-dashboard/issues/new) or contact one of the developers. You can even leave a comment on their [page](https://michaeldukes1.wordpress.com/2015/07/14/environment-dashboard-plugin-with-jenkins/). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same prob. After a bit of digging...

1) to edit (and delete! hurrah!) a Dashboard View just add a configure to the end of the URL to hit the config page

This...

http://myjenkins.local:8080/view/Dashboard1

Becomes this...

http://myjenkins.local:8080/view/Dashboard1/configure

2) the reason there were no left-hand view options in the first place 
was because  I'd ticked the following when setting up the View

Dashboard Portlets > Full screen view - hide standard Jenkins panels

So, edit the View as in (1) and uncheck that option to get your usual left-hand Jenkins View links back.

Comment: How do you delete an environment or component in an environment dashboard? When I delete the view and recreate it, everything comes back.